# Skipping security warning

Tags: excel, vba

I import data from a website which is trusted. I get a warning message from Excel.

[image: Warning message]

I tried installing this certificate several times.

What I want is, automatically click on yes, when this warning message appears.

Code to import data

```
Sub OPTIONSPULL()

For X = 1 To 7
    Worksheets("OPTIONS").Select
    Worksheets("OPTIONS").Activate

    MYSTR = "URL;https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=14NOV2019"
    MYSTR = Cells(X, 1)

    Dim STR As String, I As Integer

    For I = X To X
        STR = Cells(I, 2).Value
    Next I

    Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = STR

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        MYSTR, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=14NOV2019"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 15
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingRTF
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        .WebDisableRedirections = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next X

Worksheets("OPTIONS").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add code which You are using to connect with this website and probably I will be able to help You :)

Comment: I have added code

Comment: Try to add before `With` - `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and after `End With` - `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: Data gets refreshed every 15 min. so i don't think that above code ll work

Comment: Have You tried to record connection with that website?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you are saying but save query defination is enabled